# Javascript change object to custom array

Tags: javascript

I want to convert this object:

```
"age": [
  {
     "Under 20": "14",
     "Above 40": "1"
  }
]
```

to this:

```
 $scope data =  {rows:[ 
    {c: [
        {v: "Under 20"},
        {v: 14}
    ]},
    {c: [
        {v: "Above 40"},
        {v: 1},
    ]}
 }]
```

I've tried:

```
 $.map(resp.age, (el, key) => {
        arr.push({c: [{v: el}, {v: el}]});
 });
```

I know how to use `$.map` and `arr.push` but I can't get the key `Under 20` and take the element value `14`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: @smnbbrv Hi. Sorry about that. I copy from inspect element. I update my question with valid object

Comment: as @smnbbrv stated, your target object is not valid: You cannot have two fields of "c" inside the same object.

Comment: Can you post your code ? which you have tried ?

Comment: @jehna1 Hi. I've fix my question. @San Krish I've tried using `$.map` but I don't know the exact key. So far I only try using `$.map` and console.log the element.

Comment: if you want get "Under 20" and "14", the way you think is wrong. I suggest you Object.keys() function to get key of object.

Comment: @Miron Hi Miron. Thanks for the suggestion. Will learn more about it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
function convert(arr) {
    var ages = arr["age"][0];
    return {
        'rows': Object.keys(ages).map(function(key) {
            return {'c': [{'v': key}, {'v':parseInt(ages[key])}] };
        })
    }
}

// Usage:
convert({
    "age": [{
        "Under 20": "14",
        "Above 40": "1"
    }]
});
```

Code above outputs:

```
{"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Under 20"},{"v":14}]},{"c":[{"v":"Above 40"},{"v":1}]}]}
```

Comment: Thanks. It working great.